# iPhone phone call audio stream

Tags: iphone

Does the iPhone SDK allow you to hook into a phone call's audio stream?  For instance, could you programatically place a call and send data to a receiving modem?  If so, would you kindly point me to the API documentation?

Comment: In the answers, I saw, that it´s not possible the get the audio stream. Is this still the case in iOS14?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not.  Sorry.  You can't even programmatically place a call using the SDK, only open a `tel://5551212` link which will end your program.

Comment: Hi @marcc, is this still the case? Thanks!

Comment: It is still true, in the latest released iOS SDK.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no access to the calling features of the phone in the current SDK.

Comment: Hi @Mark Bessey, is this still the case?